# I can't find any multiplayer games for Modern Warfare 3 on Xbox 360

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, xbox-network

I completed the campaign in MW3 and it was an awesome experience. Then I head to multiplayer and looked into games that I can play.

But unfortunately there are no games to play. The search says "no games found". As I googled this is an issue that many people are currently experiencing and only happens to Xbox 360 users (which sucks).

PC and PS3 users are not having such an issue and some say that Xbox Live doesn't allow IPs from different regions to join global servers to prevent the lag, that is absolutely ridiculous. Then what's the point of having such large servers, and why are PC/PS3 users not filtered? Also, why is it that COD MW 2 and Black Ops are not having such issues?  There's definitely an issue.

So I would like to know, will they fix this issue or do they just leave it as it is, or are there any other methods that I can use to overcome this issue?

**UPDATE**
Exact issue with more details http://john385.com/

Thanks.

Comment: if you got an answer (per your blog) can you self answer your Q with the relevant details so that others can find it, etc?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood it's not my blog found it on the net while searching for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure as to why exactly you're having issues, but I play Modern Warfare 3 on Xbox Live daily, and I've never had problems.

Occasionally there are server issues, but it's been surprisingly stable since launch as far as that's been concerned.  If there's few players in the region/game type you select, sometimes the search times out, but generally you should then be placed in a lobby for other people to join you.

Is the game complaining about your NAT type?  You want your NAT type to be open.  If it is Strict or Moderate, you can usually [change settings on your router](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/connecting/nat-type-strict) to fix this issue.

If your network is properly configured, and you're logged into Xbox Live successfully, make sure you're not doing anything else on your internet connection, such as Netflix streaming or downloading/uploading large files.  This can negatively impact your latency and cause you issues when you're trying to find a game.

Beyond these things, there's no "patch" to the game in the works or otherwise available to change the network settings the game uses.

Comment: NAT type is open and I'm not streaming/downloading any Netflix videos. Question updated

Comment: Are you using wireless turtle beaches or any other wireless peripheral in the room.

Comment: No other wireless devices but I'm using a wireless router to connect my 360 to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

MW3 is region-locked. This means you can not play with people outside a certain territory you are in. This can be country or group of countries. The distinct areas are not yet known.

It is certainly not about "joining global servers". There are no real game servers. The game is hosted on one of the players machines (the game tries to choose the best possible host out of the players in the lobby). (If the host exits the game that's when "migration" happens).

So yes, it is about region locking. Lots of people have this issue. Most you can do is to petition the creators to loosen the lock with the next patch.